Why redirect in the routes file?
Reading the Ruby on Rails guide, I see this example:
get '/stories/:name', to: redirect('/articles/%{name}')

And I'm confused, when would this be helpful? Couldn't you just point the path to the controller/action like this?
get '/stories/:name', to: 'articles#show'


The example is simply showing you that you can reuse dynamic segments. Maybe your solution works and maybe not. What if the route is actually get '/articles/:article_name', to: 'articles#show' now the param in ArticleController#show is :article_name where as in /stories/:name it would be :name. This works fine with the redirection but not by pointing it directly to the controller.

You're making a false assumption that they do the same thing. When a client requests get '/stories/:name', to: redirect('/articles/%{name}') the router will respond directly with a 301 - "Moved Permanently" response and a location header. This response causes the client to send a new request which hopefully hits the right URL. get '/stories/:name', to: 'articles#show' will just dispatch the request directly to the controller and whatever response it generates is sent in the same request cycle.

They do very different things.
get '/stories/:name', to: redirect('/articles/%{name}')

Will result in the router responding directly with:
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://localhost:3000/articles/a_tall_tale

This is useful if you want to redirect requests for a legacy route to the new route and tell clients to use the new URL but don't you're not able (or too lazy) to set up a redirect on the HTTP server layer (which has even less overhead).
get '/stories/:name', to: 'articles#show'

Will dispatch the request to the controller in question and send whatever response it generates to the client.
If the goal is to support a legacy URL this won't actually tell clients to use the new URL unless you redirect from the controller and doing so would be less efficient than just doing it from the router.
